# How is it possible to pause an action of an actor in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, scene2d

I added the following action to my actor:

```
this.addAction(sequence(delay(0.5f), alpha(1, 2), delay(2), alpha(0, 2)));
```

Is there an easy way to pause this animation and then continue it when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actor is only running action, I suggest to stop calling the act() method of the actor. Extend Actor to set a switch if needed.

```
public void act(){
  if(mUpdateAnimation){
     this.act(delta)
  }
}
```

Comment: @AndreasZock I used this method, but after I unpause, my actor moves faster then before, What I want is, it should stop moving for some time and when I unpause it start moving with same configurations as before. am I missing anything? did it work for you?