# Pause and continue playing an action on actor in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying out Libgdx.
This is what I am trying to achieve,

Define an action on an Actor, while the actor is performing the action, on button click we should be able to start and stop the action, from the same position.

I tried this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511521/how-is-it-possible-to-pause-an-action-of-an-actor-in-libgdx) but after starting the action again, the actor moves faster then before, because initially we had set duration for the action to be finished, and since less time is left, it runs faster.

Can you please help? am I missing anything?

Comment: By the way, the actor shouldn't move faster. It will move faster only if you add the same action more that once. Anyway, if you share your code, it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the action from the actor on click directly from `Actor#actions` array, and then add it back on another click. Example:

```
final Actor actor = // ... initialize your actor;
final Action action = Actions.forever(Actions.rotateBy(360f, 3f, Interpolation.bounceOut));
actor.addAction(action);

actor.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        Array<Action> actions = actor.getActions();
        if (actions.contains(action, true)) {
            // removing an action with Actor#removeAction(Action) method will reset the action,
            // we don't want that, so we delete it directly from the actions array
            actions.removeValue(action, true);
        } else {
            actor.addAction(action);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: The challenge is with the duration. Do we need to compute it again depending on the remaining path? And also how to determine the remaining path.

Comment: No, it will resume exactly from the state, that it was paused in. No need to do additional math.

Comment: I tried this but this is not working in my case, it might be working in your case because rotation is an idempotent operation i.e. you can start from where ever you stopped and it will look the same, but in case of moving from a to b if you remove the action at some point x (between a and b),  now if you reapply the action it may not work, any thoughts?
can you please try with 
`SequenceAction(Action.moveTo(100,100,10), Action.moveTo(500,500,10)) `

Comment: Do you mean `Actions.sequence(
                Actions.moveTo(100,100,10), Actions.moveTo(500,500,10))` ? Anyway, I tried it, works fine. Did you try exactly like in my example? As I noted, it's important NOT to use `actor.removeAction()`, because that will call `action.reset()`. The way in example avoids that, and the action resumes in the same state, doesn't matter if the operation is idempotent or not.

Comment: At least, if you don't change the actor's position some other way while the action is removed, this approach should work as expected.

Comment: Can you share your code? Maybe I didn't understand right, what you want exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, we were trying too many things, did not realise how great the platform is. thanks again.